# C# XML serialization - float or empty element

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have xml with list of shops. Each shop have  and  nodes. In some of them this is float and in some it is empty node. So it look like this:

```
<shops>
  <shop>
    <lat>123.123</lat>
    <lon>123.123</lon>
  </shop>
  <shop>
    <lat null="true"/>
    <lon null="true"/>
</shop>
</shops>
```

My class to deserialize this xml is like that

```
[XmlRoot("shops")]
public class ShopList
{
    [XmlElement("shop")]
    public Shop[] ShopArray { get; set; }

    public class Shop
    {
        [XmlElement("lat", IsNullable = true)]
        public float? Latitude { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName="lon", IsNullable=true)]
        public float? Longitude { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

But when I deserialize xml I get error. Do you have any clues?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  Can you please more specific. What was the error ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool DataSpecified 
{ 
   get { return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Data); }
   set { return; } //The serializer requires a setter
}
```

You should try [something like this](http://danshultz.blogspot.in/2008/02/xmlserialization-nullempty-elements.html)

Answer (score -1):

I think that instead of having `null="true"` in your element, you should have `xsi:nil="true"`

```
<shops>
  <shop>
    <lat>123.123</lat>
    <lon>123.123</lon>
  </shop>
  <shop>
    <lat xsi:nil="true"/>
    <lon xsi:nil="true"/>
  </shop>
</shops>
```